# "RuntimeError: An expected Field was not found or could not be retrieved properly. [temp]" while using SearchCursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor, runtimeerror

I was trying to convert a .csv table to a geodatabase table and then write some rows that meet some conditions (using sql statement) from the table into a txt file. see the code below.

```
file_path = r'C:\Users\Documents\work\project\2011.csv'
gdb = r'C:\Users\Documents\work\project\GPS.gdb'
outfile = r'C:\Users\Documents\work\project\result.txt'

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
table = arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(file_path, gdb,'temp')
# add the columns
# replace space with _
# only use first ten characters because 
print([f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(table)])

newfile = open(outfile, 'w')
sql = '{0} = {1}'.format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(table, 'Domestic'),'true')

fields = ['Case_Number', 'Block', 'Ward']
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, fields, sql) as scursor:
    # write each row into file
    for row in scursor:
        newfile.writeline(row.join(','))
        
newfile.close()
```

Then I'm getting this error after printing the field names;

```
[u'OBJECTID', u'Case_Number', u'ID', u'Date', u'Block', u'IUCR', u'Primary_Type', u'Description', u'Location_Description', u'Arrest', u'Domestic', u'Beat', u'Ward', u'FBI_Code', u'X_Coordinate', u'Y_Coordinate', u'Year', u'Latitude', u'Longitude', u'Location']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AHMAD\Documents\work\Help_file\h.py", line 23, in <module>
    for row in scursor:
RuntimeError: An expected Field was not found or could not be retrieved properly. [temp]
```

Comment: I think your list of fields needs to contain the field name you are doing the sql on, in your case "Domestic"?

Comment: Does this line cause the error? `with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table,...` then I think `table` is not the table, it is a [Result object](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/result.htm). The table you want is named `temp`, so try `with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('temp',...`